# wchar_t and encoding

Tags: c++, character-encoding, wchar-t

If I want to convert a piece of string to UTF-16, say `char * xmlbuffer`, do I have to convert  the type to `wchar_t *` before encoding to UTF-16? And is `char*` type reqired before encoding to UTF-8?

How is `wchar_t`, `char` related to UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32 or other transformation format?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't have to change data types.

About `wchar_t`: the standard says that

> Type wchar_t is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct
>   codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified
>   among the supported locales.

Unfortunately, it does not say what encoding `wchar_t` is supposed to have; this is implementation-dependent. So for example given

```
auto s = L"foo";
```

you can make absolutely no assumption about what the value of the expression `*s` is.

However, you can use an `std::string` as an opaque sequence of bytes that represent text in any transformation format of your choice without issue. Just don't perform standard library string-related operations on it.

Comment: So can I say that using wchar_t for UTF-16 in windows platform is just a matter of choice for convenience, you can absolutely use char for UTF-16 in theory?

Comment: @Hunter: In theory yes, but in Windows, `wchar_t` is used for UTF-16, and `char` for ASCII and UTF-8.

Comment: On Windows, `wchar_t` has a known size of 16 bits

Comment: @Hunter: Yes and yes (just don't e.g. call `strlen` on a `char*` that holds UTF-16). But if you do use `wchar_t` as UTF-16 portability goes out the window.

Comment: @MooingDuck so, just because a string is in wchar_t doesn't mean it is in UTF-16, it can be UTF-8 or UTF-32 or USC2, right?

Comment: @Jon It seems like `unsigned short` is a better choise for UTF-16 with regarding to portability.

Comment: @Hunter: Slightly, but `uint_least16_t` will serve even better

Comment: @Hunter: Usually `wchar_t` means UTF16 on windows, UTF32 in linux.  `char` can be used to hold all the formats, but is usually UTF8 or a codepage.  Match whatever your framework uses.  (If windows, that is `wchar_t` holding UTF16).

Comment: @Jon If I call `strlen` on a `char*` that holds UTF-16, does it return the number of bytes?

Comment: @Hunter, if you call `strlen` on a UTF-16 string it will probably always return 0 or 1. `strlen` only accepts 8-bit characters, and will stop at the first character that has an upper byte of 0.

Comment: @Hunter: No, because e.g. `L"hello"` would be `00 68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f` in UTF-16BE, so `strlen` would return 0.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: `char16_t` is even better, but only recently added to the C++ standard.

Comment: @dan04 is `char16_t` always 16 bit in any platform?

Comment: dan04: Good call, forgot about those!  @Hunter: I don't think it's _guaranteed_ to be 16 bits, but it will be on virtually any modern machine.

Comment: According to [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2018.html), `char16_t` has to have the same size and representation as `uint_least16_t`.

Answer (score 5):

[`iconv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html) is a POSIX function that can take care of the intermediate encoding step. You can use `iconv_open` to specify that you have UTF-8 input and that you want UTF-16 output. Then, using the handle returned from `iconv_open`, you can use `iconv` (specifying your input buffer and output buffer). When you are done you must call `iconv_close` on the handle returned from `iconv_open` to free resources etc.

You will have to peruse your system's documentation about what encodings are supported by `iconv` and their naming scheme (i.e. what to provide `iconv_open`). For example, `iconv` on some systems expect `"utf-8"` and others it may expect `"UTF8"` etc.

Windows does not provide a version of iconv, and instead provides it's own UTF formatting functions: [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
//UTF8 to UTF16
std::string input = ...
int utf16len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), input.size(), 
                                               NULL, 0);
std::wstring output(utf16len);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), input.size(), 
                                &output[0], output.size());
//UTF16 to UTF8
std::wstring input = ...
int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), input.size(), 
                                              NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
std::string output(utf8len);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), input.size(),
                                &output[0], output.size(), NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Hunter: note that Windows does not come with iconv, but there are ways to get it.  @Dreamlax: Do you mind if we insert my answer into yours as a Windows alternative and remove mine?  The concept of using a library is the right one, and yours is clearer about that.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah absolutely, sounds like a good idea. Put mine in yours or yours in mine, whichever.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `wchar_t` is compiler dependent, so its relation to the various unicode formats will vary.